# Custom ostream for a println-like function

Tags: c++, formatting, io, stream, callback

I am writing a plugin in C++ that uses C API that gives me a single logging function with this signature:

```
typedef void(*println_t)(const char* text);
```

I want to wrap this type of a function in a nice `ostream` to use all C++ formatting features. Having read it is best to use `streambuf` for this, I made this code:

```
//println_buf.h

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

class println_buf : public std::streambuf
{
    typedef void(*println_t)(const char* text);
    println_t logfunc_;

    std::string buffer;
public:
    println_buf(println_t logfunc) : logfunc_(logfunc)
    {

    }

    println_buf(const println_buf &) = delete;
    println_buf(println_buf &&);
    println_buf& operator=(const println_buf &) = delete;
    println_buf& operator=(println_buf &&);

    virtual std::streamsize xsputn(const char* s, std::streamsize n) override;
    virtual int overflow(int c) override;
    virtual int sync() override;
};
```

```
//println_buf.cpp

#include "println_buf.h"

using namespace std;

println_buf::println_buf(println_buf &&o) : logfunc_(o.logfunc_), buffer(std::move(o.buffer))
{

}

println_buf& println_buf::operator=(println_buf &&o)
{
    logfunc_ = o.logfunc_;
    buffer = std::move(o.buffer);
    return *this;
}

streamsize println_buf::xsputn(const char* s, streamsize n)
{
    streamsize start = 0;
    for (std::streamsize i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == '\n')
        {
            buffer.append(s + start, s + i);
            sync();
            start = i + 1;
        }
    }
    buffer.append(s + start, s + n);
    return n;
}

int println_buf::overflow(int c)
{
    char ch = traits_type::to_char_type(c);
    if (ch == '\n')
    {
        sync();
    } else {
        buffer.append(1, c);
    }
    return c;
}

int println_buf::sync()
{
    logfunc_(buffer.c_str());
    buffer.clear();
    return 0;
}
```

Usage:

```
println_t logfunc = ...;
println_buf buffer(logfunc);
std::ostream stream(&buffer);
stream << "Hello world" << std::endl;
```

It should be noted that `println_t` includes a newline automatically in the actual output, but I want to have to specify the line separator in C++.

My concern is that the function should not be called with a string containing `\n`, but the string must be passed to the function only if it originally ended with `\n`, and be buffered otherwise. Also `endl` should cause the function to be called immediately.

Answer (score 2):

I'll review more later but a basic comment first.

Rather than write just the `println_buf` class I would also write the `println_stream` class that internally has a `println_buf`.

```
class println_stream: std::ostream
{
    // Make this a private class.
    // You don't need to leak implementation details.
    // As far as anybody else is convered it is just std::streambuf
    class println_buf { /* STUFF */ };

    println_buf     buf;
    std::streambuf* oldBuf = nullptr;
    public:
        println_stream()
            // You can't pass the buf to the ostream constructor
            // here as it has not been constructed yet.
            // There are ways but lets keep it simple for now.
        {
            // I did not do the work with logfunc
            // Have not read that bit yet.
            // But you get the idea I hope.
            oldBuf = rdbuf(&buf);
        }
        ~println_stream()
        {
            // Can't remember if it is required.
            // But I would always set back the original buffer.
            rdbuf(oldBuf);
        }
};

int main()
{
   println_stream stream;
    stream << "Hello world\n";
}
```

Comment: Later never happened  ... still +1.